# How to properly store time with timezone data in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Is there a standard format for storing hours with time zone data ? I don't want to store the date just the time.

Comment: Perhaps you want to check moment.js. https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript times are all **[ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)** (and based on **[UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)**), so automatically include the date by default. There is no harm in including dates when simply working with time calculations, as you can easily simply ignore them if necessary, and the dates can also provide additional information if you ever require it (such as timespans across multiple days).

The **best** way to work with time in JavaScript is with the **[`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/date-object-javascript)** object, which also comes with handy methods for getting the day, hours, minutes and seconds:

```js
var the_date = new Date();

var year = the_date.getFullYear();
var month = the_date.getMonth();
var day_month = the_date.getDate(); // Day of the month
var day_week = the_date.getDay(); // Day of the week

var hours = the_date.getHours();
var minutes = the_date.getMinutes();
var seconds = the_date.getSeconds();
var milliseconds = the_date.getMilliseconds();

console.log(the_date);

console.log(year);
console.log(month);
console.log(day_month);
console.log(day_week);

console.log(hours);
console.log(minutes);
console.log(seconds);
console.log(milliseconds);
```

Remember that many of these indexes start at **zero**, so you'll likely want to add `1` to most of them!

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Date.now()` to store the raw date data, and use [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) library, to parse and format. Make sure you get used to [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) when dealing with dates in js, this is the most adopted and trusted library to work with dates.